# syntax issue with jquery css function and css 3 transforms

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I have created a js fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/gNTPz/

I am trying to dynamically insert a value into the translateX transform function using the jquery css function

here is my js

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    var j = 1, k=50;
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {                     
        k = 50 + k;
        var div = "#box-"+j
        //$(div).css('margin-left', k-50+'px');
        $(div).css('-webkit-transform','translateX(k-50px)');
        j = j+1;
        if (j > 5) {
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        }
    }, 400) // end setInterval      
});
```

the line that is commented out actually works

```
$(div).css('margin-left', k-50+'px');
```

However I am trying to use css transform function instead and am having difficulty with the syntax to use a variable within the transform translateX function.
here is what I want to do

```
$(div).css('-webkit-transform','translateX(k-50px)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just do:

```
$(div).css('-webkit-transform','translateX('+(k-50)+'px)');
```

I presume you need the quotes so that Javascript doesn't get confused between the String concatenation and Integer addition

Comment: that is what I was looking for thanks - for 10 minutes I was trying to figure it out and kept getting errors because I didn't put my quotes in the right place